# I get Inconsistent query results

Tags: sql

When I send a search string from my web page to my online database, I sometimes get an error :

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

The query is :

```
"SELECT * FROM tblImagesExifSQL WHERE SourceFile LIKE '" +  document.getElementById('searchtxt').value + "'"
```

It happens when I use `%` to find the string anywhere in the data e.g.

```
%dad%
```

The search returns records sometimes or the above error, depending on the string I enter. I use a php program to send the query to the database. The query always works if I paste the query into the SQL window in phpMyAdmin .e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM tblImagesExifSQL WHERE SourceFile LIKE '%baby%'
```

I have queried the host manager (Hostinger) but they can't figure it out either.

I just discovered I was using the wrong syntax for the query - I am now using

```
"SELECT *, SourceFile LIKE '" +  document.getElementById('searchtxt').value + "' FROM tblImagesExifSQL"
```

Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM tblImagesExifSQL WHERE SourceFile LIKE '%baby%'

"SELECT *, SourceFile LIKE '" +  document.getElementById('searchtxt').value + "' FROM tblImagesExifSQL"
```

I'd still be interested to know why the other syntax gives such inconsistent results. It used to work ok until about 48 hours ago.

Comment: Hi my name is [Bobby Tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/), I'm looking for my `mom'; DROP TABLE tblImagesExifSQL; --`. Have you seen my mom?